Get data on different rows per ID on one row
My data looks like:



ID
Year
Volume1
Volume2




AAA
2023
10
20


AAA
2024
5
10


BBB
2023
20
40


BBB
2024
30
60



I would like to have the volumes per ID all on one row, where ideally the column names are extended with the year separated with an underscore sign.
What I want to have:



ID
Volume1_2023
Volume2_2023
Volume1_2024
Volume2_2024




AAA
10
20
5
10


BBB
20
40
30
60



How can I do this in PostgreSQL?

What about just one JSONB column in the result like {"volume1_2023": 10, "volume1_2024": 5, "volume2_2023": 20, "volume2_2024": 10}? It will be more usable in the logic tier. Your expected results' table would grow wider and wider with the years.

@Stefanov.sm Good point. However, the goal of this table is just to compare values of the current year with the previous year per row. A json structure won't work for this.

The non cross tab pivot query approach here would be:
SELECT
    ID,
    MAX(Volume1) FILTER (WHERE Year = 2023) AS Volume1_2023,
    MAX(Volume2) FILTER (WHERE Year = 2023) AS Volume2_2023,
    MAX(Volume1) FILTER (WHERE Year = 2024) AS Volume1_2024,
    MAX(Volume2) FILTER (WHERE Year = 2024) AS Volume2_2024
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID;


But what happens in the year 2025?

You write more code?  2025 is not part of the OP's question.

My suggestion is to aggregate years and volumes into a JSONB column.

Great suggestion...is upvote possible?

Appreciate. I will shape it as an answer.

First, enable the tablefunc extension (if it's not already enabled).
Then execute this query, replacing "your_table_name" with your actual table name:
SELECT *
FROM crosstab(
    'SELECT ID, 
            CONCAT(''Volume1_'', Year) AS Volume1_Year, 
            Volume1, 
            CONCAT(''Volume2_'', Year) AS Volume2_Year, 
            Volume2
     FROM your_table_name
     ORDER BY ID, Year'
) AS ct(
    ID text, 
    Volume1_2023 int, 
    Volume2_2023 int, 
    Volume1_2024 int, 
    Volume2_2024 int
);


My suggestion is to aggregate years and volumes into a JSONB column.
select id, 
    jsonb_object_agg('volume1_'||year, volume1) || 
    jsonb_object_agg('volume2_'||year, volume2) as volumes
from the_table
group by id; 

DB Fiddle Demo



id
volumes




BBB
{"volume1_2023": 20, "volume1_2024": 30, "volume2_2023": 40, "volume2_2024": 60}


AAA
{"volume1_2023": 10, "volume1_2024": 5, "volume2_2023": 20, "volume2_2024": 10}



